# "You need to use a theme.appcompat theme" with Theme.AppCompat as theme, Sdk v23

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

Config:

```java
Android Studio 1.4 Preview 2
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23'
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
Up-to-date support libraries (v23)
```

Error:  [updated]

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.android.debug/com.myapp.mobile.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.k.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
        at com.myapp.mobile.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:47)
        at com.myapp.mobile.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My application was working well before switching to v23 (previous config was v22 and support libraries v22.2.1. After upgrading, compilation is done correctly but this error appears just at launch.

I have seen many posts on SO where the problem comes from a bad styling, with a Holo parent. Tricky problem found their origin in Manifest file, where an activity theme overrides app theme.

It's my case, so I changed for test purpose my manifest to:

```xml
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.BaseMyApp">

    <!-- Launch activity. MyApp.Theme has Theme.BaseMyApp for parent, but has 2 more attributes for v21 -->
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

... but, how strange, the error still occurs! I also have checked views of activity layout, but nothing seems to be a problem, only a Toolbar which theme extends AppCompat:

toolbar_layout.xml

```xml
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
    app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.SubTitle"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
        style="@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar.Progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

where

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Customize color of navigation drawer icon and back arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <!-- Set proper title size -->
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar</item>
    <!-- Set title color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.SubTitle" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle">
    <!-- Set proper title size -->
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_subtitle_material_toolbar</item>
    <!-- Set title color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>


<style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar.Progress" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:minHeight">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">25dp</item>
</style>
```

Do you have an idea where I have messed it up?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, as it may give us more clues as to where the problem lies.

Comment: Do you assign another theme for one of your activities which is not an AppCompat theme?

Comment: your app may indeed have the AppCompat theme but one of your Activities might not have that theme for whatever reason

Comment: Such an honor to have you here @CommonsWare. It's the classic runtime exception, I update my post.

Comment: OK, are you sure that you do not have an `android:theme` attribute on the `<activity>` element for `HomeActivity`?

Comment: I'm sure I haven't, I promess. But I use paypal SDK, which imports activites in my final manifest, but that shouldn't be a problem at app launch. As @ThomasR mentionned, it could be because of ThemeOverlay, I naively thought it was an extension of Theme.AppCompat, I will try when I'm home.

Comment: @guillaume_fr post your entire manifest please

Comment: @tyczj done for the relevant part, the rest isn't, I think. Other activities have just an <activity name=""></> tag. But what's very strange is that everything's fine when I use v22.

Comment: @guillaume_fr what is `android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme"` you said to @CommonsWare that you didnt set the theme of your `HomeActivity` but you clearly did

Comment: @tyczj these themes are my original themes, which correctly have for god parent "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar". Yet, the problem occurs even if I set android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" just for application theme. That's why I think the problem comes from what ThomasR said, a bad toolbar theme extension.

Comment: OK. The line "at android.support.v7.app.k.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)" seems to say that app.k. class has been obfuscated. The code runs well when minifyEnabled=false. But when it's true, I have the "unable to compute hash" error, it's depressing.

Comment: Now, errors come from libraries which use removed (!!) methods of v23 SDK, like `Warning:com.paypal.android.sdk.aT: can't find referenced field 'org.apache.http.HttpEntity wrappedEntity' in program class com.paypal.android.sdk.aT` or `Warning:uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher: can't find referenced method 'float sqrt(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath`. I don't think there is a workaround for PhotoView, other than fork the repo to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem partially solved.

The guilty line is:

```java
at android.support.v7.app.k.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
```

I use [these separate ProGuard files](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets) to configure ProGuard. Maybe I didn't point to the correct `/app/proguard` directory. Thus, ProGuard ignored `myapp-rules.pro` where I say to keep those `android.support.v7.**`classes.

After fixing this, I had the error:

```java
:app:proguardDebug
Warning: com.paypal.android.sdk.aT: can't find referenced field 'org.apache.http.HttpEntity wrappedEntity' in program class com.paypal.android.sdk.aT
Warning: uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher: can't find referenced method 'float sqrt(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
Warning: uk.co.senab.photoview.gestures.CupcakeGestureDetector: can't find referenced method 'float sqrt(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
    Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
    You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.
     You probably need to update the library versions.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
:app:dexDebug
:app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug
:app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsDebug
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Unable to compute hash of
/home/guillaume/workspace/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/debug/classes.jar
```

So I 'fixed' the warnings by adding rules

```xml
-dontwarn com.paypal.android.sdk.**
-dontwarn uk.co.senab.photoview.**
```

Yet the problem seems deeper, as PhotoView and Braintree/Card.io (also PayPal SDK) use methods removed with API 23. The ball is not in my count, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your update. Maybe your toolbar parent is the problem. It has another inheritance than Theme.AppCompat.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
  <!-- Customize color of navigation drawer icon and back arrow -->
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Try using this for your toolbar:

```
"Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"
```

as parent

Comment: Thank you @ThomasR I will try it, I let you inform. I naively thought ThemeOverlay.AppCompat was "compatible" with Theme.AppCompat. Compat overdose.

Comment: It did not solve the problem, and after the error, I cannot run the app as there is an error during app:packageDebug --> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Unable to compute hash of /home/guillaume/workspace/myapp/app/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/debug/classes.jar

Comment: Did you try to clean your workspace? Could you please post the code of your BaseActivity and HomeActivity? Maybe we get an idea what is going wrong.